# Running same MySQL query twice in a row and getting different results

Tags: php, mysql

With the code below, if I copy and paste that into a php file 2x, one after the other, the first one will print `"There are results"` and the second one will print `"0 results"` even though it is the same query. Why is that?

```
$query = "SELECT id, spent_before_added_main FROM ltv_table WHERE DATE(`table_entry_created`) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)";

$result = $conn->query($query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "There are results ";
} else {
     echo "0 results ";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: both of them in same file? or in different file?

Comment: Both in the same php file.

Comment: Instead of echoing _if_ here are results or not, you should _look at the actual results_ to see how they differ.

Comment: it is possible that you've already closed the connection on the 2nd part. did you copy just the query onwards? try not to copy the connection close and move it to the bottom

Comment: and `$conn->close();` this line in between both queries?

Comment: Yes, that is what it was.  The code does that because the $conn->close() closes the connection, so the second one can't run. Thanks!

Comment: great @Jordan: glad to help u